# Trying to submit an update to an app in XCode, but I keep getting an error…

Tags: ios, xcode

"There is no embedded java executable. Please reinstall the Xcode developer tools."

Anybody encountered this before? I'm on Lion and with the beta version of Xcode, so I'm sure that has something to do with it.

Comment: Apple generally don't allow submissions to the App Store using beta software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that apple make some checks in your bundle, Im in the same situation, I've added *base sdk* as 10.6 and target to *any osx* but didn't happen. Then I used the old Application Launcher of x-code 4.0 and he say: *the application is built with a wrong version of sdk*.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not exactly sure what's causing the java executable error, or why that would in any way relate to my obj-c project, but it seems that either way I can neither upload with Lion nor with a beta build of Xcode, so I had to get a computer with Snow Leopard on it.

Comment: Mmm so in your opinion what happen? Why using as target 10.6 and Sdk 10.6 I can't push my app? I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Even using Xcode 4.1 GM (which was stated to allow submissions to the app store) I was getting this error - I re-installed Xcode using the AppStore (Xcode is now free).

Note that when installing from the app store you are not asked for an install location, it simply uses /Developer - so keep Xcode 4.2 in a separate folder (or re-install after as I had to).

Comment: Can you elaborate what was your solution? Was it to download Xcode via the Mac App Store?

Comment: I did two things - One, I downloaded Java for Lion.  After that, I installed XCode from the App Store.  I am not sure installing Java to start with did anything, but it might help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your XCode to the latest (4.2.1 as of now). Go to the App Store and search for Xcode. If you already have 4.2 but have a hard time finding how to update to 4.2.1 or above, after press the "install" in the App Store Xcode App, go to the Finder > Applications and run the "Install XCode" app to either install or upgrade.

After finish, go to "About" in Xcode menu bar and check to see the XCode version again to make sure the upgrade/installation was successful.